# Adding a Back Button on A Table View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, segue

I am interested in implementing a back button to segue to a previous view controller. I have tried to embed a navigation bar onto the the top of the table view controller but the issue is when I do segue back to the first view controller, by default, Xcode keeps the navigation bar with a back button to go back to the table view controller. Is there a simpler way to implement a segue to go back to the first VC without the navigation bar remaining? [image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, and the image doesn't help. I'm guessing you want to implement an unwind segue. Have a look at this tutorial - https://www.raywenderlich.com/113394/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2

Comment: you don't want a navigation bar, but you want a back button , is that what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure if this works, but embed your view controllers including the first one inside the navigation controller. That would make all your view controllers with navigation bar above.

On the main view controller (the one you do not want to have the navigation bar), add the line of code inside your `viewDidLoad` method.

Swift 3:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
```

Comment: For swift 3: self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true worked! Thanks for pointing me in this direction!!

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy way. On your TableViewController, drag a UIview to the top of the view controller and itll let you insert the view. From there just add your back button

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just assign your "Back" UIBarButtonItem to this method and it should work.

```
@IBAction func backButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a few problems

1) How are you navigating from the first view controller? Is it with `Show (Push)` if not, you are replacing the first view controller in your stack.

2) Based on your problem, make sure your first view controller is not embedded in a navigation controller

3) As Dylan mentioned, you need to hook your back button to remove the current view controller to return to the first one

4) Extension of (3), how are you segueing back to the first view controller? If you are explicitly navigating to first view controller with your back button handler, it's not actually going back but rather forward and keep the navigation bar.